# C++ class template derives from templated class: is there a better way of writing this?

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring

I wonder if the following code could be written better:

```cpp
template< typename DataType >
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass< std::vector< DataType > >
{
public:
    typedef std::vector< DataType> ListDataType;

    // ...
};
```

Specifically, I would like to eliminate the extra mention of 'std::vector', but this is of course illegal:

```cpp
template< typename DataType >
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass< ListDataType >
{
public:
    typedef std::vector< DataType> ListDataType;

    // ...
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I encounter something like this frequently. This is common. This is C++. That's what it is.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are attempting to use any container type and not have it always be vector, or just trying to not type `std::vector` in multiple places.

Comment: getting terminology straight can safe you some confusion. `MyDerivedClass` is a class template and it derives from a class. There are no template classes in C++

Comment: Do you use `ListDataType` in the derived class itself? Or only your users need it?

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is just to avoid writing `std::vector` twice, you can define an additional helper template parameter for it.

```cpp
template< typename DataType, typename U = std::vector<DataType> >
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass< U >
{
public:
    using ListDataType = U;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: It's too easy to override `U`. :(

Comment: I see that more as a feature rather than a bug :)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. `std::vector` occurs only once and can be changed easily, if that should become neccessary.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: you can do without the second template parameter by adding an alias definition template at global scope: `template< typename DataType> using ListDataType = std::vector< DataType>;` and replace `MyBaseClass<U>` by `MyBaseClass<ListDataType< DataType>>`